# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have JSON PHP Output below

```
{"data_0":{"data_1":{"A":0,"B":0},"data_2":{"C_C":"CC","D_D":"DD"}}}
```

In jQuery have code :

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'process.php',
    dateType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data : {val : data_val},
    success: function(data){
        $(data.data_0.data_2).each(function(key, value) {
        alert(key + " " + value);
        });
```

But when run I received error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data_2' of undefined.

How to fix it ?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Use `$.getJSON` method instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: you have to use `JSON.parse()` with post requests, even if you set the content type to JSON with `$.ajaxSetup({args});` As far as im a ware, `$.getJSON()` is the only jQuery ajax method that will automatically parse json for you.

Comment: Try something like this:


$.each(data['data_0']['data_2'], function (key, value) {
  alert(key + " " + value);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
dateType: 'json',
```

to this;

```
dataType: 'json',
```

You have a type it should be `dataType` not `dateType`.

---

Also you should use `$.each()` utility method of jQuery instead of `.each()`:

```
$.each(data.data_0.data_2, function(key, value) {
    alert(key + " " + value);
});
```

#### [*$.each() docs:*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The $.each() function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.

Comment: Oh. Can't believe. Thank you so much :)

Comment: But now I received : 0 [object Object] ?

Comment: @Ivan use `$.each()` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: Yes, It working like charm. What different between '$(data.data_0.data_2).each' and '$.each(data.data_0.data_2' ? Thanks you

Comment: `.each()` works on collections like array, but if you want to loop on objects then ofcourse you have to check with `$.each()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json first using `JSON.parse()`

```
$.ajax({
url : 'process.php',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
data : {val : data_val},
success: function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $(data.data_0.data_2).each(function(key, value) {
    alert(key + " " + value);
    });
```

Comment: I received : 0 [object Object] ?

Comment: Because alert can not display object, if you want to see whats inside object than you can use `console.log(value)` and look in inspect element console

Comment: I want add key and value to select tag with code :
$('#select-data')
        .append($("<option></option>")
        .attr("value",key)
        .text(value)); 
But It only so key = 0 and value = [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Please fix like [Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793685/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-json/27793846#answer-27793745) has suggested you, and For key and value take a look on this example:

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"data_0":{"data_1":{"A":0,"B":0},"data_2":{"C_C":"CC","D_D":"DD"}}}');
var keys = Object.keys(data.data_0.data_2);

for(var i in keys) {
    alert("Key:"+keys[i]+", value:"+data.data_0.data_2[keys[i]]);
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/th1yhhr7/)**